# How display formatted text in EditText?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

Now I am writing simple note app. And i need to display formatted separate selected text in EditText.

I tried,

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String string;
int startSelection = et.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection = et.getSelectionEnd();

string = et.getText().toString();
string.substring(startSelection, endSelection);



Spanned s = Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"red\">" + string + "</font>");

et.setText(s);
```

This solution displays only separate selected text. But i need to display formatted text among other text. I have no idea.

UPD: Formatting happening, when user clicks on the button.

Comment: You want Like this? "Simple Text **Formatted Text** Simple Text Again"

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
EditText text = new EditText(this); 
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
String string = et.getText().toString();
    String selectedString = string.substring(startSelection, endSelection);

    Spanned s = Html.fromHtml(string.replace(selectedString, "<font color=\"red\">" + selectedString + "</font>"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Its great solution, but i need display formatting text after next formatting. Formatting happening, when user clicks on the button. That means: I need to save formatted text even after another formatting text.

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about formatting the Text, You can always do like this

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
et.setText(Html.fromHtml("Simple Text <B>Formatted Text</B> Simple Text Again"));
```

And If you want to `linkify` a specific part of the Text then do it like this using this [Blog](http://www.sherif.mobi/2011/09/html-and-activity-links-in-textview.html)

```
    EditText mTextSample = new EditText(this);
    String text = "click to see stackoverflow.com here";   
    mTextSample.setText(text);        
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("stackoverflow.com");   
    Linkify.addLinks(mTextSample, pattern, "http://");
```