# Android EditText does not show all text

Tags: java, android, html, android-edittext, textview

I have a code which retrieves HTML source code of a page. I can retrieve and display the full source code on a TextView without any problem. Then, I want to pass all content of TextView to EditText in order to enable Editing the code. But when I pass source code to EditText, EditText does not show all of the code. The code is broken from random locations. It shows some part of the code. I am totally tilted.

Some details:
TextView is in another activity and EditText is in another activity, I am passing TextView content to EditText with Intents.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

BR,
Ali

Comment: What part does it show and not show.  Do you have a max size?  Are you using a multi-line edit text?  Some pictures may help to describe your problem.

Comment: it is random, sometimes it splits text and only shows first part. It is very weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363042/android-how-display-formatted-text-in-edittext

Comment: Giru Bhai, did I ask anything related to formatting text inside EditText? Please read carefully.

Comment: @user10214 Are you setting intent values to edittext,right?is that value contain all text,which you want to display,then please post your second activity code.

Comment: I am sending with: bg.putExtra and receiving it with: getIntent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the time, I have counted the number of characters that I am passing to the edittext, it is revealed out that whatever website source code I am previewing the count is 10000. And the solution is so simple:

android:maxLength="100000"

That is it! Now I can view up to 100000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EditText text = new EditText(this); 
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```